# Rayleigh quotient for Robin boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I'm reading Walter Strauss' PDE book. In section 11.4 he said that the Rayleigh quotient of the following Robin eigenvalue problem

$$
\begin{cases}
  -\nabla\cdot(p\nabla u) + qu = \lambda mu, & \text{in }D \\
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} + au = 0, & \text{on }\partial D
\end{cases}
$$

is

$$
Q = \frac{\int_D p|\nabla w|^2+qw^2 dx + \int_{\partial D} aw^2 dS}{\int_D mw^2 dx}.
$$

I'm wondering whether there is a typo. I think the numerator should be

$$
\int_D p|\nabla w|^2+qw^2 dx + \int_{\partial D} \color{red}paw^2 dS.
$$

Am I right?

Comment: \begin{align}
\int_{D} - u \nabla \cdot (p \nabla u) dx \underbrace{=}_{\text{div. thm}} &\int_{\partial D} - u p \nabla u \cdot n dS + \int_{D} (p \nabla u) \cdot \nabla u dx \\
= &\int_{\partial D} a \color{red}{p} u^{2} dS + \int_{D} p \lvert \nabla u \rvert^{2} dx
\end{align}

So yes, you are right, it is a typo.

Comment: OK, thanks@MatthewCassell